# xamarin form : how to change label with stepper

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want to increment or decrement value of label based on stepper value change, but stuck here. Here is my code

```
<ListView x:Name="mylistview"


  >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"   Text="{Binding Qty, StringFormat='Qty. {0:N}'}" FontSize="11"
                   TextColor="Black" />

                    <Stepper ValueChanged="stepper_ValueChanged"   Minimum="0" Maximum="10" x:Name="stepper" Value="{Binding Qty}" Increment="0.1" HorizontalOptions="LayoutOptions.Center" VerticalOptions="LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand"  />

                </StackLayout>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: if the Label and Stepper are bound to the same property, this should work, but your VM must implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.In the code,if you just want bind label text to stepper you can do this.*

```
<ListView x:Name="mylistview">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" BindingContext="{x:Refrence Name=stepper}"  Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat='Qty. {0:N}'}" FontSize="11"
               TextColor="Black" />

                <Stepper ValueChanged="stepper_ValueChanged"   Minimum="0" Maximum="10" x:Name="stepper" Increment="0.1" HorizontalOptions="LayoutOptions.Center" VerticalOptions="LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand"  />

            </StackLayout>

        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

*just add bindcontext to label,then bind stepper's value,this labe text can be changed by stepper.if have a problem,you can refer to here[official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings)*

*2,When you use modle bingding data,you should use INotifyPropertyChanged to your modle,if this do not have ,the value can not be changed.*

*3,when you use modle,according to your code the **Qty** should be contained to listview's itemsource,not contained just in BindContext,so the **Qty** can be useful.*

Answer (score 0):

How you can achieve is through below steps, if you are using MVVM

1. Have a model property for Label (which raises propertychanged event handler) which displays the count.
2. In the stepper_ValueChanged, get the object (model data) associated with that view cell and in the view model, code it to set/change the count property of label based on the value change.

Comment: here is my code how i am getting data n listview for qty `await _connection.CreateTableAsync<LocalItems>();
            var abc = await _connection.Table<LocalItems>().ToListAsync();
            _LocalItems = new ObservableCollection<LocalItems>(abc);
            mylistview.ItemsSource = _LocalItems;`

Comment: You need to change the value of the particular item object and need to set itemsource to the list view again